# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null at checkSessionExpired

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
document.getElementById("processingDivAdd").style.display = '';
        document.getElementById("messageDivAdd").innerHTML = '';
        xmlhttp.open("POST",url,true);
        xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "text/xml");
        xmlhttp.send(dataString);

        // Set the callback
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function(){
            if ( xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status == 200 ) {
                document.getElementById("processingDivAdd").style.display = 'none';
                if(!checkSessionExpired(xmlhttp.responseXML)){
                    return;
                }
                document.getElementById("addToBook").innerHTML = xmlhttp.responseText;
                document.getElementById("addConfig").innerHTML = '';
                setup();
            }
        }

function checkSessionExpired(xmlDoc)
{
    var xAttribute = xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName('attribute');
    if(xAttribute[0] != null && xAttribute[0].childNodes[1] != null)
    {
        if(xAttribute[0].childNodes[1].firstChild.nodeValue == 'TIME_OUT')
        {
            alert("Your session was timed out due to inactivity. Please Login to continue"); 
            document.location.href = 'login.jsp'; //...and redirect to login page.
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

This code seems to work fine on IE older versions(version 5) but its not wroking on chrome giving error

Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getElementsByTagName' of null
    at checkSessionExpired

what could be the issue?. The xmldoc is null in chrome.

Comment: Are you passing the correct argument to the function?

Comment: getElementsByTagName accepts as an argument name (p, span, div etc.). You provide attribute. it's wrong

Comment: @JanuszO That's still a tag name, notice _XML_. Also, the problem occurs before, since `xmlDoc` is not defined or is `null`.

Comment: "cannot read `x` of *null*" means that the variable on the left of `x` is null - `xmlDoc.getElementsByTagName` means `xmlDoc` is null - nothing to do with the parameters to the call

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/responseXML - "*null if the request was unsuccessful, has not yet been sent, or if the data can't be parsed as XML or HTML*" - most likely the last

Comment: Check `dataString`, perhaps it is different in Chrome and IE, and your server can't handle the data send by Chrome correctly ..?

Comment: @Teemu its the same in bith IE and Chrome the datastring

Comment: But that's the only thing which _could_ differ in the code, anything else is Chrome compliant. Please re-check.